# Gmail API and size of attachment

Tags: android, google-api, gmail, email-attachments, gmail-api

I am using Gmail API on Android and I have a problem for file attachment.

I followed example below:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending#creating_messages_with_attachments

and the problem is arisen here:

```
String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes.toByteArray());
```

I want to attach a video file about 8MB, but this line shows 'out of memory' error.

It is okay when I send image file attachment. (Typically below 1MB).

How can I deal with it?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know android, so I may be way off base, but their code shows:

```
mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileDir + filename);

mimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
mimeBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
String contentType = Files.probeContentType(FileSystems.getDefault()
    .getPath(fileDir, filename));
```

You are encoding the `base64` directly, which explodes into a fairly large string.  The `FileDataSource` likely works around that.